# Durrett's Probability problem 3.1.1, show $\prod_{j=1}^n (1+c_{j,n}) \to e^\lambda$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Given: $$\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |c_{j,n}| \to 0$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n  c_{j,n} \to \lambda$$
$$\sup_n \sum_{j=1}^n |c_{j,n}| < \infty,$$
show that:
$$ \prod_{j=1}^n (1 + c_{j,n}) \to e^\lambda.$$

**My partial solution:** Taking the log of both sides, the conclusion is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \ln (1 + c_{j,n}) \to \lambda.$$
Indeed,
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \ln (1 + c_{j,n}) =  \sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{\ln (1 + c_{j,n})}{c_{j,n}} c_{j,n}.$$
Let
$$ \overline{c}_{j,n} := \max_{1\leq j \leq n} c_{j,n},$$
$$ \underline{c}_{j,n} := \min_{1\leq j \leq n} c_{j,n}.$$
Now define
$$k_n := \frac{\ln (1 + \underline{c}_{j,n})}{\underline{c}_{j,n}},$$ 
and 
$$l_n := \frac{\ln (1 + \overline{c}_{j,n})}{\overline{c}_{j,n}}.$$ 
Clearly, for all $n$ and all $1 \leq j \leq n$,
$$ l_n \leq \frac{\ln (1 + c_{j,n})}{c_{j,n}} \leq k_n.$$
Using the first assumption, $l_n,k_n \to 1$.
Assuming that $\lambda>0$, we write
$$ l_n \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j,n} \leq \sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{\ln (1 + c_{j,n})}{c_{j,n}} c_{j,n} \leq k_n \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j,n},$$
and finally, using the squeeze theorem, and the second assumption, our result follows. (If $\lambda<0$, the inequalities switch sides.)

**My question:** I haven't used the last assumtion, so I'm guessing something is missing in my solution.

Comment: Recall that $$
\log(1+x) = x - \frac12 x^2 + O(x^3)
$$
and so $$\frac{\log x}x\stackrel{x\to 0}\longrightarrow 1. $$

Answer (score 2):

Your last inequality is not true. Indeed, $l_n\sum_n c_{j,n}$ may not be less than $\sum_n \log(1+c_{j,n})$ because $c_{j,n}$ can be negative. One way to prove this problem is by evaluating the difference.

$$
\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\log(1+c_{j,n})-\sum_{j=1}^nc_{j,n}\right|\le\sum_{j=1}^n\left|\frac{\log(1+c_{j,n})}{c_{j,n}}-1\right||c_{j,n}|\le \max_{1\le j\le n}\left|\frac{\log(1+c_{j,n})}{c_{j,n}}-1\right|\sum_{j=1}^n|c_{j,n}|
$$

The last term goes to zero as you can check by the three assumptions.